# Added faces-config.xml but still getting Target Unreachable

Tags: jsf, annotations, jetty

I have a JSF app running on embedded jetty. It works when I run it from eclipse but not from command line. I realised it was because eclipse uses the folders and cli uses the jar. I assumed, after googling, it was because my jar was missing a `faces-config.xml`. I added one in the META-INF folder but I'm still getting `Target unreachable` errors for the beans in my xhtml.

[image: Pic of faces-config.xml]

How can I check that JSF is in fact scanning my jar for `@ManagedBean`?

Ps. I build my projects' jar with maven, copy it to my lib folder then run it from cli with `java -cp "lib\*" com.test.MainSystem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging `AnnotationConfiguration` I could see that Jetty only scans jars under `WEB-INF`.

Fortunately, they provide a method for adding external jars. Adding this got me up and running...

```
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();

// Add "this" jar to the list of jars to scan for annotations
String jarPath = JettyServer.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
webapp.setExtraClasspath(jarPath);
```

Comment: Why did you not just  put it in the WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: I don't have one, it's embedded.

Comment: Embedding does not mean you can't have these... You can (and should as it prevents a lot of other possible issues). See for some hints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136088/updating-embedded-jetty-webapp-in-eclipse-during-run/33155355#33155355

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So are you saying I should set the directory inside my jar as the base resource?